# How to denormalize a nested Map in Scala, with the denormalized string containing only values?

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, denormalization

I am new to Scala and FP in general and wanted to know how a nested collection can be denormalized in Scala. For example, if we had data of a question paper for an exam as:

```
Map("subject" -> "science", "questionCount" -> 10, "questions" ->
  Map("1" ->
    Map("ques" -> "What is sun?", "answers" ->
      Map("1" -> "Star", "2" -> "Giant bulb", "3" -> "planet")
    ), "2" ->
    Map("ques" -> "What is moon?", "answers" ->
      Map("1" -> "Giant rock", "2" -> "White lamp", "3" -> "Planet")
    )
  )
)
```

When denormalized into strings, using only the values, it can be written as:

```
science,2,1,What is sun?,Star
science,2,1,What is sun?,Giant bulb
science,2,1,What is sun?,planet
science,2,2,What is moon?,Giant rock
science,2,2,What is moon?,White lamp
science,2,2,What is moon?,Plane
```

I understand that I can use `map` to process each item in a collection, it returns exactly the same number of items. Also, while `flatMap` can be used to process each item into multiple items and return more items than in the collection, I am unable to understand how I can do the denormalization using it.

Also, is it possible to do a partial denormalization like this?

```
science,2,1,What is sun?,[Star,Giant bulb,planet]
science,2,2,What is moon?,[Giant rock,White lamp,Planet]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with nested maps of type `Map[String, Any]` will never be pretty because you always have to cast the nested values.

If you want a `String` for every answer, you can `flatMap` over the questions and then `map` over the answers.

```
def normalize(map: Map[String, Any]): Seq[String] = {
  val subject = map("subject")
  val questions = map("questions").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
  val size = questions.size // or map("questionCount") ?
  val lines = questions.flatMap { case (id, q) => 
    val question = q.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
    val answers = question("answers").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
    answers.values.map(answer => 
      List(subject, size, id, question("ques"), answer) mkString ","
    )
  }
  lines.toSeq
}
```

If you want a `String` per question (partial denormalization), you can just `map` over the questions.

```
def seminormalize(map: Map[String, Any]): Seq[String] = {
  val subject = map("subject")
  val questions = map("questions").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
  val size = questions.size // or map("questionCount") ?
  val lines = questions.map { case (id, q) => 
    val question = q.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
    val answers = question("answers").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
    List(subject, size, id, question("ques"), answers.values.mkString("[", "," , "]")) mkString ","
  }
  lines.toSeq
}
```

We could use `normalize` and `seminormalize` as :

```
scala> normalize(map).foreach(println)
science,2,1,What is sun?,Star
science,2,1,What is sun?,Giant bulb
science,2,1,What is sun?,planet
science,2,2,What is moon?,Giant rock
science,2,2,What is moon?,White lamp
science,2,2,What is moon?,Planet

scala> seminormalize(map).foreach(println)
science,2,1,What is sun?,[Star,Giant bulb,planet]
science,2,2,What is moon?,[Giant rock,White lamp,Planet]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question entries of Map used differently:

1. Here they have to be sequences: `Map("subject" -> "science", "questionCount" -> 10, ...`
2. Here they have to create different rows: `Map("1" -> "Star", "2" -> "Giant bulb",...`

So, first I suggest to introduce notion of Sequence and notion of Choice

Then I would implement denormalization as follows:

```
object Runner3 extends App {
  case class Sequence(items: List[(String, Any)])
  case class Choices(items: List[Any])

  val source = Sequence(List(
    "subject" -> "science",
    "questionCount" -> 2,
    "questions" -> Choices(List(
      Sequence(List(
        "ques" -> "What is sun?",
        "answers" -> Choices(List("Star", "Giant bulb", "planet")))),
      Sequence(List(
        "ques" -> "What is moon?",
        "answers" -> Choices(List("Giant rock", "White lamp", "Planet"))))))))

  def denormalize(seq: Sequence): List[List[String]] =
    seq.items.map {
      case (_, choices: Choices) => denormalize(choices)
      case (_, otherValue) => List(List(otherValue.toString))
    }.reduceLeft(
        (list1: List[List[String]], list2: List[List[String]]) =>
          for(item1 <- list1; item2 <- list2) yield item1 ::: item2
      )
  def denormalize(choices: Choices): List[List[String]] =
    choices.items.flatMap {
      case seq: Sequence => denormalize(seq)
      case otherValue => List(List(otherValue.toString))
    }

  denormalize(source).foreach(line => println(line.mkString(",")))
}
```